# Rename an uploaded file with PHP but keep the extension

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm using PHP to upload an image from a form to the server and want to rename the image lastname_firstname.[original extension].  I currently have:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["picture"]["tmp_name"], "peopleimages/" . "$_POST[lastname]" . '&#95;' . "$_POST[firstname]")
```

which, of course, renames the file lastname_firstname without an extension. How do I rename the file but keep the extension?

Thanks!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You need to first find out what the original extension was ;-)

To do that, the **[`pathinfo`](https://www.php.net/pathinfo)** function can do wonders ;-)

Quoting the example that's given in the manual :

```
$path_parts = pathinfo('/www/htdocs/index.html');
echo $path_parts['dirname'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['basename'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['extension'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['filename'], "\n"; // since PHP 5.2.0
```

Will give you :

```
/www/htdocs
index.html
html
index
```

As a sidenote, don't forget about security :

- In your case, you should escape `$_POST[lastname]`, to make sure it only contains *valid* characters

  - And, BTW, you should use `$_POST['lastname']` *-- see [Why is `$foo[bar]` wrong?](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.foo-bar)*
- You should also check that the file is an image

  - See [`mime_content_type`](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php) for PHP < 5.3
  - And/or [`finfo_file`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php) for PHP >= 5.3

Comment: I also use the 

    is_uploaded_file()

function to check if the file we're pointing at is actually an uploaded file.

Comment: @Niels Bom: `move_uploaded_file` does it for you.

Answer (score 4):

You can try:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["picture"]["tmp_name"], "peopleimages/" . "$_POST[lastname]" . '&#95;' . "$_POST[firstname]".".".end(explode(".", $_FILES["picture"]["tmp_name"])))
```

or as  Niels Bom  suggested

```
$filename=$_FILES["picture"]["tmp_name"];
$extension=end(explode(".", $filename));
$newfilename="$_POST[lastname]" . '&#95;' . "$_POST[firstname]".".".$extension;
move_uploaded_file($filename, "peopleimages/" .$newfilename);
```

Comment: That is a *long* line of code, most coding standards advise against that because of poor readability. I suggest you follow them.

Answer (score 4):

Dont forget if you are allowing people to upload arbitrary files, without checking the, extension, they can perfectly well upload a .php file and execute code on your server ;)

The .htaccess rules to deny php execution inside a certain folder is something like this (tailor for your setup)..

```
AddHandler cgi-script .php .pl .py .jsp .asp .htm .shtml .sh .cgi
Options -ExecCGI
```

Put this into a .htaccess file into the folder where you are uploading files.

Otherwise, just bear in mind that files may have more than one "." in them, and you should be golden.

Answer (score 3):

this code is insecure

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["picture"]["tmp_name"], "peopleimages/" . "$_POST[lastname]" . '&#95;' . "$_POST[firstname]". $extension);
```

if

```
$_POST[firstname] =mypicture.php%00
```

and

```
$extension=.jpg;
```

this code is vulnerable and result is

```
test.php%00.jpg //test.php uploaded on server.
```

for more information check this link:

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Unrestricted_File_Upload

Answer (score 2):

First, find the extension:

```
$pos = strrpos($filename, '.');
if ($pos === false) 
{
    // file has no extension; do something special?
    $ext = "";
}
else
{
    // includes the period in the extension; do $pos + 1 if you don't want it
    $ext = substr($filename, $pos);
}
```

Then call your file anyhow you want, and append to the name the extension:

```
$newFilename = "foobar" . $ext;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'], 'peopleimages/' . $newFilename);
```

---

**EDIT** Thinking of it, none of this is optimal. File extensions *most often* describe the file type, but this is not always the case. For instance, you could rename a .png file to a .jpg extension, and most applications would still detect it is as a png file. Other than that, certain OSes simply don't use file extensions to determine the type of a file.

With `$_FILE` uploads, you are also given a `type` element which represents the MIME type of the file you've received. If you can, I suggest you rely on it instead of on the given extension:

```
$imagetypes = array(
    'image/png' => '.png',
    'image/gif' => '.gif',
    'image/jpeg' => '.jpg',
    'image/bmp' => '.bmp');
$ext = $imagetypes[$_FILES['myfile']['type']];
```

You can have a [more complete list of MIME types here](http://www.webmaster-toolkit.com/mime-types.shtml).

Answer (score 0):

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["picture"]["tmp_name"], "peopleimages/" . "$_POST[lastname]" . '&#95;' . "$_POST[firstname]." . pathinfo($_FILES["picture"]["tmp_name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
```

Comment: That is a *long* line of code, most coding standards advise against that because of poor readability. I suggest you follow them.

Answer (score 0):

you could always:

```
$original = explode('.', $_FILES["picture"]["tmp_name"]);
$extension = array_pop($original);

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["picture"]["tmp_name"], "peopleimages/" . "$_POST[lastname]" . '&#95;' . "$_POST[firstname]". $extension);
```